# cannot find the file created under cygwin using the search from microsoft windows 7

Tags: windows-7, unix, cygwin

I am a Windows 7 user and have a large text file (>3 GB) to process and extract information.

I chose to run cygwin under Windows 7 to split the file as I do not know how to do it using DOS command line. `split -l 300000 /cygdrive/c/users/a/desktop/folder1/file1` generates 28 new files from file1.

While `ls` shows the names of these 28 new files, using Windows 7 search, I cannot find where the new files are.

The home directory under cygwin is `/home/user` but when I use `ls` to show where those new files are, I got the following without an explicit path

> $ls xaa
>
> xaa

Q. Under Windows 7, how else can I find out where those 28 files are (as each file will be ~70 MB, I certainly would remove them later to save some extra space in the hard drive)?

Q. can we convert the /home/user or xaa to a Windows/DOS directory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty happy with [Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/) that search **MUCH** faster than window's search. Run it as a service with admins rights and I'm pretty sure it will find what you are looking for.

As about to "convert the /home/user or xaa", you don't need to convert anything, "/home/user" located in the root path where you installed `cygwin`.

just run

```
cygpath -w -p /home/user
```

to get "windows" directory path